# Java: external archives not accesible

Tags: java, user-interface, compiler-errors

I am working on a class within a package within a source folder within a project with `Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)`.

First I did not organize my files well, so I had to move them using `Refactor --> Move`. Now I created a class within a source folder. On that particular source folder I right clicked and choose `Build Path --> Add External Archives`, I then selected a UI library and all worked well.

Now I reorganized my classes and moved them to a different project, where I created source folders and packages for the classes. All the classes work well, expect for the one that uses the UI interface. But here is the part that puzzles me: I can not add an external archive anymore. When I right click on the project, I find `Build Path --> Configure Build Path` as the only option. Now I can select `Libraries` and choose `Add extneral JARs`, but this does not make the class work as it did before. In stead, I get errors on all the lines referencing the UI, saying: `the type *** is not accessible` or `*** cannot be resolved to a type` and even line where I do not use the interface but simply introduce a string give an error: `The type java.lang.String is not accessible`.

I am new to Java and completely puzzled. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: UI commands you mentioned (e.g. "Refactor --> Move") depends on concrete UI. There are many IDEs. We don't know which one you use. Try to localise the issue by doing small steps and see what happened. This will help you to spot the issue and understand why it's an issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I use Eclipse!

Comment: Nitpick: It's Java, not JAVA, it's not an acronym.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. Apparently there was a `package-info.java` file created in another package which was in the same source project. This, for some reason, blocked the UI-interface. After deleting this file and removing the `JRE System Library` from `Build Path --> Configure Build Path`, then adding the exact same `JRE System Library` fixed the problem.